# Cursor-highlighting in quickfix-window: QuickFixCmdPre overriding QuickfixCmdPost?

Tags: vim, vim-quickfix

I would like my quickfix-window to have some highlighting for the current line of the cursor.

After some research I found that I could configure the general appearance of the current line using `set cursorline` and `highlight CursorLine term=bold cterm=bold guibg=Grey40`.

Now, I only want that when I'm in the quickfix-window though. So I started to wrap these 2 lines inside a function and called that function with a autocommand:

`au QuickFixCmdPre * call EnableSearchHighlighting()`

So far, so good. Since I still have the highlighting activated after I searched at least once, I needed to disable the effect again. **And here is where I am stuck**...

I wrote another function to just `set nocursorline` and call this one on the `QuickFixCmdPost`-Event. But for some reason this broke everything. Now I won't get the highlighting anymore, not even in the quickfix-window.

It feels like the Post-Event overrides the Pre-Event.
I'm not sure what else to try here.

Maybe anyone can help me out or even has another approach to the highlighting in the first place?

Here is the full code as it is in my .vimrc right now:

```
function EnableSearchHighlighting()
  set cursorline
  highlight CursorLine term=bold cterm=bold guibg=Grey40
endfunction

function DisableSearchHighlighting()
  set nocursorline  
endfunction

au QuickFixCmdPre * call EnableSearchHighlighting()
au QuickFixCmdPost * call DisableSearchHighlighting()
```

Thanks for reading. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach has many problems, but the main one (and the reason it doesn't work) is that both `QuickFixCmdPre` and `QuickFixCmdPost` are run for each quickfix command before you get to switch to the error window.

Add this to a file `ftplugin/qf.vim`:

```
setlocal cursorline
```

Then add the `highlight` definition to your `vimrc`, outside any function or `autocmd`:

```
highlight CursorLine term=bold cterm=bold guibg=Grey40
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. So, do I understand correctly that qf.vim is a special file that is supposed to contain all the settings around the quickfix-window? Is it convention to name the folder that contains this file ftplugin? Anyway, your solution worked flawlessly, thank you!

Comment: One possible flaw is that the highlight settings are global, not only for QF window. @AvantiC: You can google for ftplugin for more info.

Comment: FWIW I had to also add `setlocal cursorlineopts=line` to override a different setting I use everywhere else